# Appium Android-Taking more than 2 minutes to find/click on a mobile element on a real device

Tags: appium, appium-android, python-appium, appium-desktop, appium-java

I'm new to Appium and was designing a simple testcase to find an element and to click on a mobile element. I used real devices(Android) instead of emulators. It took about 2 mins or more to find the element and click on the element. As choosing Xpath to find elements in Android is a slower strategy, I used Accessibility Id but couldn't find any difference in the performance.

```
newstart_ele=driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.ACCESSIBILITY_ID,value="NewstartButton")
newstart_ele.click()
```

Appium Python Client-> v2.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Lowering waitForIdleTimeOut might help. See [here](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/14155).